# Why does STM32CubeIDE crashes constantly with "BAD_POOL_HEADER" bluescreen

Tags: ide, bluescreenview

I installed the current STM32CubeIDE 1.3.0 on my home computer with Windows 7* but it keeps crashing with bluescreens with the error *BAD_POOL_HEADER*. I could not make out any specific action I do before the computer crashes, sometimes it happens when compiling, sometimes when switching perspective and sometimes when trying to flash the code to the controller connected to a ST Link. And sometimes it runs for hours before crashing, but most of the time it's more a matter of minutes.

I already did a clean reinstall of the CubeIDE using the default program path (*C:\ST* instead of *C:\Program files\ST*) but that did not change anything.

I'm not so much an IT guy so I'm having a hard time figuring out what the problem is. I used *BlueScreenView* to check the minidump but I can not read anything useful from the log. Can anybody suggest to me how to figure out what the problem might be?

[image]

* *I know support ended, but right now I still did not manage to get everything I need running on linux, so Win 7 will have to do for a little longer. This is not what this question is about.*

Comment: Bad Pool Header is often a memory issue. Update ALL your drivers and then (if you have more than one memory module) check memory modules one at a time. Find memtest86.exe (Google) and run two or three passes of the memory tester.  Get your vendor's hardware test application and run that as well.

Comment: Memtest showed no errors, all passes where OK. Do you think it really might be the memory modules, despite the fact that the CubeIDE is the only tool that keeps crashing? I have no such problems with any other software at all.

Comment: Did you update all the other drivers?  If the memory test passed, then it is not likely memory.  It is hard to suggest where the addressing error may come from.

Comment: I reinstalled the ST Link USB driver (which already was the latest) and checked for a new chipset driver - but there is only a 7 year old experimental beta driver, that is not recommended for productive systems  (I did NOT install that), I guess they never bothered releasing a stable version. I guess other drivers should not have any effect here. I will write to the support of ST, but I doubt that they have any idea.